# Expanding existing ZFS loop device

Tags: lxc, lxd

I have several LXC containers on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. I have a container called "cloud" which I want to expand its storage, how can I do this without reinstalling? I am using ZFS for this.

```
user@server:~$ zfs list -t all
NAME                                                                                               USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
default                                                                                           89.4G  7.01G    24K  none
default/containers                                                                                87.7G  7.01G    24K  none
default/containers/doc                                                                            1015M  7.01G  1.24G  /var/lib/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/doc
default/containers/git                                                                             324M  7.01G   577M  /var/lib/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/git
default/containers/docsys                                                                          476M  7.01G   633M  /var/lib/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/docsys
default/containers/cloud                                                                           85.0G  7.01G  85.3G  /var/lib/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/cloud
default/containers/nginx                                                                           280M  7.01G   435M  /var/lib/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/nginx
default/containers/storage                                                                         214M  7.01G   466M  /var/lib/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/storage
default/containers/test                                                                            448M  7.01G   603M  /var/lib/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/test


user@server:~$ lxc storage list
+---------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------+---------+
|  NAME   | DESCRIPTION | DRIVER |             SOURCE             | USED BY |
+---------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------+---------+
| default |             | zfs    | /var/lib/lxd/disks/default.img | 8       |
+---------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

LXD 3 or newer supports the creation of additional storage pools. 
Therefore, create an additional storage pool and then move the big container to the new storage pool.

Here is an example.

1. Create an additional pool. Here we give 100GB of space.

   ```
   lxc storage create secondpool zfs size=100GB
   ```
2. Support the container is called `bigcontainer`. We move it with `lxc move`, specifying that it should be placed inside the new storage pool. During the moving, we have to rename the container because we move within the same LXD server.

   ```
   lxc move bigcontainer bigcontainer-moved --storage secondpool
   ```